.NET MAUI Application is not supported on Visual Studio Mac
When I tried to run the MAUI project on Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac, I faced the error below.
Error: Could not find any available provisioning profiles for ApplicationName on iOS.

I fixed the above error by deleting the .vs, obj, and bin folders on the project and deleting the aps-environment key from Entitlements.plist  as suggested on this thread and also from Visual Studio I tried to clean and rebuild the solution. After that, the MAUI project is installed on the iOS simulator, but the application does not open and shows the alert below.
you can't open the application "Application Name" because this application is not supported on this Mac.

Screenshot:

I have added the signing certificate and provisioning profile to the Project, but after that, I am facing the error below.
 Error NETSDK1147: To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: maui-ios
To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore (NETSDK1147)

This is the first time I am running the MAUI app on my Mac. I installed the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac and Xcode. Any other softwares do I need to install the proper working of .NET MAUI on Mac?
Can you please provide me with a solution to resolve this issue?

Do you have any provisioning profiles associated with your Apple developer account? Did you configure automatic provisioning?

@Julian I have updated the question with more findings, could you please check that.

You didn't answer my question. You need code signing certificates and provisioning profiles for your app: See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning and https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/ios/capabilities

@Julian I have updated the question with more findings, could yo please check that.

Have you tried running dotnet workload restore as suggested by the error message? It seems that the installation of the MAUI workloads might be corrupted on your machine. Try installing maui-ios manually by running dotnet workload install maui-ios, if the other command doesn't resolve the issue.

After installing .net workloads the issue is resolved.
